# how to get the distance between two locations or points?

Tags: android

I am trying to calculate the distance between two points in my app I used the below code but i do not get the result.

```
  package in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationroutemylocationv2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    ArrayList<LatLng> mMarkerPoints;
    double mLatitude=0;
    double mLongitude=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        }else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Initializing 
            mMarkerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

            // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
            mGoogleMap = fm.getMap();

            // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


            // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location From GPS
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location!=null){
                onLocationChanged(location);
            }

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);           

            // Setting onclick event listener for the map
            mGoogleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                    // Already map contain destination location 
                    if(mMarkerPoints.size()>1){

                        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();   
                        mMarkerPoints.clear();
                        mGoogleMap.clear();
                        LatLng startPoint = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);
                        drawMarker(startPoint);
                    }

                    drawMarker(point);

                    // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
                    if(mMarkerPoints.size() >= 2){                  
                        LatLng origin = mMarkerPoints.get(0);
                        LatLng dest = mMarkerPoints.get(1);

                        // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                        String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);                

                        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                        // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                        downloadTask.execute(url);
                    }                   
                }
            });         
        }       
    }

    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;          

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";         

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;      

        return url;
    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url 
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url 
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                        sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
                iStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
     }



    /** A class to download data from Google Directions URL */
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{         

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try{
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;        
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
            super.onPostExecute(result);            

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);

        }       
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Directions in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread        
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject; 
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;                     

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);    
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

            // Traversing through all the routes
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                    HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);                 

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng); 

                    points.add(position);                       
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(2);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);   

            }

            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            mGoogleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);                            
        }           
    }   


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void drawMarker(LatLng point){
        mMarkerPoints.add(point);

        // Creating MarkerOptions
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

        // Setting the position of the marker
        options.position(point);

        /** 
         * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
         * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
         */
        if(mMarkerPoints.size()==1){
            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
        }else if(mMarkerPoints.size()==2){
            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
        }

        // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(options);      
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Draw the marker, if destination location is not set
        if(mMarkerPoints.size() < 2){

            mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
            mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
            LatLng point = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);

            mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));        

            drawMarker(point);          
        } 

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }   
}
```

This is the above code i am using but i do not got the result.
so,can anyone help me?

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14394366/find-distance-between-two-points-on-map-using-google-map-api-v2/33365083#33365083

Comment: LocationManager do have a function to calculate the distance between 2 geos

Comment: find working code from:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886356/finding-road-distance-between-two-coordinates-in-google-map-android/48088851#48088851

Answer (score 1):

if you know your from and to LatLng then try the below code it will return the distance in KM.

```
try {
        Location mallLoc = new Location("");
        mallLoc.setLatitude(markerLatLng.latitude);
        mallLoc.setLongitude(markerLatLng.longitude);

        Location userLoc = new Location("");
        userLoc.setLatitude(uLoc.getLocation().getLatitude());
        userLoc.setLongitude(uLoc.getLocation().getLongitude());

        float distance = mallLoc.distanceTo(userLoc) / 1000;
        return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%.2f", distance)
                + " km Away";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        return "Unknown";
    }
```

where markerLatLng is your **to** LatLng

uLoc is your **from** LatLng

Comment: Please provide detailed information about above code for example where to write and how to implement

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: if you use Google Maps API you can simply use [this function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location))...

---

Read [here](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1366331/dotnet/langages/csharp/calcul-distance-entre-2-coordonnee-gps/#post7411336):

```
protected double DistanceTo(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, String unit)
{
    double rlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180.0f;
    double rlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180.0f;
    double rlon1 = Math.PI * lon1/180.0f;
    double rlon2 = Math.PI * lon2/180.0f;

    double theta = lon1-lon2;
    double rtheta = Math.PI * theta/180.0f;

    double dist = Math.sin(rlat1) * Math.sin(rlat2) + Math.cos(rlat1) *     Math.cos(rlat2) * Math.cos(rtheta);
    dist = Math.acos(dist);
    dist = dist * 180.0f/Math.PI;
    dist = dist * 60.0f * 1.1515f;

    if (unit=="K") { dist = dist * 1.609344f; }
    if (unit == "M") { dist = dist * 1.609344 * 1000f; }
    if (unit == "N") { dist = dist * 0.8684f; }
    return dist;
}
```

And then in your "onLocationChanged":

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Draw the marker, if destination location is not set
    if(mMarkerPoints.size() < 2){

        // warning for the first point, mLatitude, mLongitude are NULL
        double distanceinmeters  = DistanceTo(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), mLatitude, mLongitude, "M");

        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng point = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);

        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12));        

        drawMarker(point);          
    } 

}
```

Comment: This is going to give you the distance as the bird fly. If you need the distance by road, this will not fit your needs.

Comment: Of course. PS: moreover I did not see that he was using Google Maps API ... (EDIT)

Comment: Please provide detailed information about above code for example where to write and how to implement

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
public double CalculationByDistance(LatLng StartP, LatLng EndP) {
            int Radius = 6371;// radius of earth in Km
            double lat1 = StartP.latitude;
            double lat2 = EndP.latitude;
            double lon1 = StartP.longitude;
            double lon2 = EndP.longitude;
            double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
            double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
            double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
                    + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
                    * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
                    * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
            double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
            double valueResult = Radius * c;
            double km = valueResult / 1;
            DecimalFormat newFormat = new DecimalFormat("####");
            int kmInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(km));
            double meter = valueResult % 1000;
            int meterInDec = Integer.valueOf(newFormat.format(meter));
            Log.i("Radius Value", "" + valueResult + "   KM  " + kmInDec
                    + " Meter   " + meterInDec);

            return Radius * c;
        }
```